# Sketch 3 - Export Layer without transparent pixels

Tags: layers, export, sketch-app

I have created an artboard with some shapes overlay on each other. I want create a png export from the red one.(its actual size is 111*111) but when I drag and drop the red layer to the finder, its dimension is 232 × 311. it includes transparent pixels.

how can I export the layer with its exact size?
[image]
I don't want to use slices. because it will includes other layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so when I opened the file the oval was 215x215... I just clicked on export on the bottom right and it exported normally without any of the other shapes in the background or size problems.

[image: Export Button]
[image]

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my sketch app after deleting and installing it again it doesn't trim transparent Pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Hashem I'm super late, but if you haven't already found the answer, give this a shot. On the top right when you've highlighted the layer you want to export, check the box that says 'trim transparent pixels'

Alternatively, you could just move that one shape onto another art board and then slice it.

[image]

Comment: I just want to drag and drop my shapes to desktop. If I add an slice to them I have to check trim transparent pixels and export group contents only repeatedly for every object. thats cumbersome. Im looking for a way to just drag and drop my shapes. Sketch should be smart enough to know I want only the shape without any transparent pixel but it seems it doesn't knoW or I don't know!

Comment: can you send me the sketch file to help me better understand

Comment: here is the sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6kliulp2uccuzz/drag%20%26%20drop.zip?dl=0